# Can updating same value from two sessions cause a deadlock in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, locking, database-deadlocks

I have an application where user clicks a button on UI which triggers an oracle function. I want to avoid multiple parallel runs of that function in DB (at a time there should be only one ongoing run). Can I use below custom locking mechanism to achieve this without worrying about deadlock?

**My Approach -**

1. Flag will be initially set as NULL
2. If multiple sessions triggers the function at the same time then only one of them will continue because only one them will be able to update flag
3. Function will update flag back to NULL after processing is done

**DDL**

```
create table test_oracle_lock (id int, flag varchar(1), primary key (id));
```

**Custom Locking Code to avoid parallel runs**

```
update test_oracle_lock set flag = 'In Use' where flag is null and id = 1;
updated_rows := sql%rowcount;
commit;
IF updated_rows = 0 then --if unable to update flag (i.e. unable to acquire custom lock) then exit function
  EXIT;
ELSE
  --execute all sql statements to process data and update flag back to NULL
  update test_oracle_lock set flag = NULL where flag = 'In Use' and id = 1;
END IF;
```

Comment: A few things: 1.) If you are going to do it this way, make sure you put an exception block which resets your lock, otherwise you’ll be locked out forever if one of your queries fail. 2.) Check out dbms_lock, why build something new if the functionality exists. 3.) Any session will take a lock out before updating rows, so this is likely unnecessary.

Comment: Dbms_lock is better, and even if you really want to use own table, I would prefer `select for update ` with wait N or `nowait` clausr

Comment: How to use dbms_lock to achieve same functionality?

Comment: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2005/10/user-named-locks-with-dbms_lock/

Comment: Do you mean a [deadlock](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/deadlocks) specifically, which is a scenario where two sessions bracket each other's locks in such a way that neither session can either proceed or back out, or just a blocking lock?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I meant deadlock where two sessions block each other. I just want to avoid deadlock situation.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is `select ... for update` on the table. Do that at the beginning and you don't have to worry about manual locking. It will only lock the row in question, so won't interfere with other sessions and if there is a rollback, it's automatically released.

```
select id into l_id from my_table for update.
```